# How do I get the build to automatically update a web service reference in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, build-process, flexbuilder

From within FlexBuilder3, I can go to "Data/Manage Web Services..." select a web service, and click "Update" to ensure that my code and the server are in sync. How do I automate this so that each time I build, the automatically generated web service code is regenerated?

If the server interface changes during development but my code doesn't, it won't work anyway - I'd rather have a compilation error than a runtime error I had to track down to a changed web service interface.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can not update a web service at build time. The update is part of the wizard and is not implemented as a separate action to be called on demand.

One suggestion I have is to go in the project properties and inside the **Build** panel add as a new builder a program. You will have to create this program that checks each time the project is build that the WSDL file did not change. It is a little bit complicated but if you are working on a project that relies on a web service that is under heavy development it might save you a lot of time.